# Cannot properly match and extract parameters from a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm sitting about 2 hours trying to extract parameters from a string. No matter how many parameters it has.

Consider this (example),

```
$template = "/category/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/";
$input    = "/category/username/category-id/2";

And I would like an array of parameters to be like this,

Array (
    [0] => username
    [1] => category-id
    [2] => 2
)
```

So, I've started from,

```
$replacements = array(
    '(:any)'        =>  '.+(?=/|$)',
);

$str = '/category/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)';
$str = str_replace(array_keys($replacements), array_values($replacements), $str);

$input = '/category/username/category-id/2';

$pattern = '~^' . $str . '$~';

preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);

print_r($matches);

// That prints Array ( [0] => /category/username/category-id/2 )
```

But now I'm stuck with proper parameter extracting. The very first that that comes to mind is to find similar values between two strings and remove them. Then remove `(:any)` and `/`.

```
$template = "/category/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/";
$input    = "/category/username/category-id/2";
```

The problem is that, it will require a lot of extra work relying on `explode()`.

**So the question is** : (take a look at the first code example):
How can I properly achieve that using a regular expression, that would match and properly put parameters in `$matches`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this regex should work:

```
$replacements = array(
    '(:any)'        =>  '([^/]*)',
);

$template = "/category/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/";
$input    = "/category/username/category-id/2";

$str = '/category/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)';
$str = str_replace(array_keys($replacements), array_values($replacements), $str);

$input = '/category/username/category-id/2';

$pattern = '~^' . $str . '$~';

preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => /category/username/category-id/2
    [1] => username
    [2] => category-id
    [3] => 2
)
```

Comment: That returns the same `Array ( [0] => /category/username/category-id/2 )`, while I'd like it to be `Array ( [0] => username [1] => category-id [2] => 2)`

Comment: You need to use `preg_match_all` I believe.

Comment: Well, `preg_match_all()` returns almost the same: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => /category/username/category-id/2 ) )`

Comment: @DaveJust: See full code in my answer, you just needed capturing group in your `$replacements` array. Output is also shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_split()` function like this:

```
$pattern = "/[\/]/";
$parameters = preg_split($pattern, "/category/username/category-id/2");
array_shift($parameters);
array_shift($parameters);
var_dump($parameters);
```

this code splits the string into an array by delimiter `/`. the structure is like this:

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(0) "" 
    [1]=> string(8) "category" 
    [2]=> string(8) "username" 
    [3]=> string(11) "category-id" 
    [4]=> string(1) "2" 
}
```

then by using `array_shift()` 2 times the result would be:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "username" 
    [1]=> string(11) "category-id" 
    [2]=> string(1) "2" 
}
```

I'm using the words **username,category_id,...** and they could be variables too.

Answer (score 0):

Same as @1linecode but without using regex.

```
$url = "http://somedomain.com/category/username/category-id/2";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$params = explode('/', $path);
array_shift($params);
array_shift($params);
```

Output:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "username" [1]=> string(11) "category-id" [2]=> string(1) "2" }
```